# How to change month number in month name in Carbon Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I have a table with a period and sales column.
the period look like this

- 2017001
- 2017002
- ......
- 2017011
- 2017012

I use the Carbon extension to extract the month number into month name with

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(substr($saleCurrent->period, -2))->month }}
```

but i'm getting an error

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (01) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character

This is because the month should be 1 not 01 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the CreateFromFormat method so that you can pass in the format your dates are stored in:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', $saleCurrent->period)->month }}
```